# How to implement Tags

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, tags

I'm developing an application where i need to show the tags for every discussion and every comment as shown in image below. I'm getting the tags from service something like this.

```
tags =             (
                Registration,
                Apps,
                PublicSpeaking,
                Marketing,
                Sales
            );
```

I want these tags to display under "tag" part of the given image.

[image]

this is how i was trying to implement, any kind of tutorial or link will be very helpful.

```
for (int i=0; i< [self.menuListArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *tag_string = [self.menuListArray objectAtIndex:i];
    CGSize tagSize = [tag_string sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:13.0]
                         constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(230, FLT_MAX)
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
    UIImageView *tag_bgimage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [tag_bgimage setFrame:CGRectMake(i*tagSize.width+5, stringSize.height+5, tagSize.width+4, 25)];
    [tag_bgimage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [tag_bgimage setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    UILabel *tagLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [tagLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tagSize.width, 25)];
    [tagLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [tagLabel setText:tag_string];
    [tagLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:12.0]];
    [tagLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    [tag_bgimage addSubview:tagLabel];
    [cell addSubview:tag_bgimage];
```

}

Comment: can you explain some more .what is tag doing here

Comment: Can you be more specific.. do you want to show more than 3 tags or some thing else ?

Comment: tag is just to identify that this discussion comes under what all topic. like in stackoverflow we need to set the tags for asking question.

Comment: tags can be in any number. more than 3  also.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=token look here is the showing token filed which can you extend into your code

Comment: what actually you need in this... do you want the background image view to be the size of tag text.?

Comment: So you want to set the tag on imageview and label??

Comment: Yes. I'm getting tags from the service something like this. `tags =             (
                Registration,
                Apps,
                PublicSpeaking,
                Marketing,
                Sales
            );`
i want to display them under "Tag" part in the given image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/domness/DWTagList) controller. That looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using addition framework, I recommend UICollectionView to implement Tags. It's less code, less overhead and easy to implement.

Follow this link for implementing:

https://codentrick.com/create-a-tag-flow-layout-with-uicollectionview/

This is how it looks like. Please note it is flexible too.

[image]

Hope this will help you